# Xamarin Form Reactive UI MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

Currently I have using reactiveui `RoutedViewHost` to navigate around my Android app.

I wanted to use the new `MasterDetailPage`, is it supported in reactiveui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment - you can certainly use ReactiveUI without routing though, it's an entirely optional feature

Comment: Is this still the case?